# Is it valid : $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac \alpha n\right)^n=e^\alpha$ at $\alpha$ is complex?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, solution-verification

I started the problem $\lim_{n}\left(1+\frac in\right)^n$, and I get the right answer $\cos1+i\sin1$. Then I expanded it for arbitary complex $\alpha$. Is my proof-sequence is correct?

**Proof of** $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac \alpha n\right)^n=e^\alpha$

Start using complex logarithm(multi-value), then limit will change $\lim_n n\log\left(1+\frac\alpha n\right)$, and using Taylor, then $\log(1+\frac\alpha n)\sim\frac\alpha n+2im\pi$.($m$ is integer.)

So, $\lim_n n\log\left(1+\frac\alpha n\right)=\lim_n n\cdot\left(\frac\alpha n+2i\pi m\right)=\alpha+2i\pi N$($N$ is also integer.)

Using exponent at both side, then the proof ends since $e^{2i\pi N}=1$.

Is it right? I'm not sure in two parts.

1. I avoided using single-value branch cut $\text{Log}$ function because there exists singularity, but if $n$ sufficiently large, then $1+\frac \alpha n$ is not on branch cut. Is it right? Then was avoiding $\text{Log}$ no use?
2. Is $N$ used right way?

Comment: You can assume that $n \gg |\alpha|$ and just use the principal branch of the logarithm, since $n$ will tend to infinity anyway and $\alpha$ is fixed. So you can write $$
\log \left( {1 + \frac{\alpha }{n}} \right) = \frac{\alpha }{n} + \mathcal{O}_\alpha\!  \left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right).$$

Comment: Perhaps another idea for a proof.  Both $f_n(a) := \left(1+\frac \alpha n\right)^n$ and $f_n'(a)$ converge locally uniformly in $a \in \mathbb C$ as $n \to \infty$ and the limit $f(a)$ satisfies the differential equation $f'(a) = f(a)$, $f(0)=1$.